# Layout Shifts And `width` / `height` Attributes On `img`

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm a bit confused by how the `width`/`height` attributes of the `img` element are interpreted.  [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/whats-the-difference-between-width-height-in-css-and-width-height-html-attributes/) says

> Those attributes are sometimes referred to as presentational attributes. The thing to know about them is that they are overridden by any other styling information whatsoever. That makes them ideal as a fallback.

but I did some experiments, and it seems that those attributes can indeed prevent a layout shift, even when the CSS styles set some width (e.g. `100%`).  Also MDN states

> Including height and width enables the aspect ratio of the image to be calculated by the browser prior to the image being loaded. This aspect ratio is used to reserve the space needed to display the image, reducing or even preventing a layout shift when the image is downloaded and painted to the screen.

which confirms my observations.

But then I usually put `* { all: unset; display: revert; }` in my CSS (inspiried by the [New CSS Reset](https://elad2412.github.io/the-new-css-reset/)) and with this addition, layout shifts seem to came back.  I also used https://pagespeed.web.dev/ to verify this.  Any idea what property I'm unsetting here which shouldn't be unset?  It is not `width` and `height`, i.e. adding `img { width: revert; height: revert; }`  did not solve this.  Even `img { all: revert; }` didn't help, so it seems that it's not about the image's properties.

Comment: grid is a dynamic container that will align elements and resize them dynamically to fit the grid. as such it will overwrite a width and height attribute which has a lower specificity weight then CSS.

Comment: Yes, but with the aspect ratio information it should be able to compute the layout before the actual image has loaded, just from the HTML and CSS.  After the images load, having those attributes specified make no difference of course.

Comment: I see no place where you specify the aspect ratio. width and height attributes do not declare the `aspect-ratio`-property in any case. Only if they actually apply they will indirectly set an aspect-ration by the fixed width and height in pixels.

Comment: But that's what I meant, if you try it, it seems that the browser computes the aspect ratio from `width` and `height`, so e.g. a 750x500 image with `width` set to `3` and `height` set to `2` will not cause a layout shift (in the case of `width: 100%` in the CSS) because the browser expects a 3x2 image, then the 750x500 image comes but it makes no difference in the displayed height.

Comment: So my understanding is that *if* the browser sees the image dimensions in the HTML, it can always compute the actual layout before the image actually loads.  But this seems to be not always the case and I wonder why or if it's different between browser implementations.

Comment: That's the issue in your logic. an image has a default width and height and as such a default aspect-ratio. If you use the width property or attribute of 100% value then the original default aspect-ratio will be maintained. If you use a width and height attribute, you overwrite the default width and height and force that specified sizing while ignoring the default aspect-ratio. You not declaring an aspect-ratio to the image by that. And no the browser does not know the sizing of the image before it is loading.

Comment: What can happen is working on the ISO transportation layer where meta data of the files is send with. it also contains information that can be read out before the full information the actual data (image itself)  is received. It is like you telling the browser that an image with the dimension of 1920x1080 pixel will be received and then that the browser should await the detailed instructions about the image itself (where the color of every single pixel is ended).

Comment: Look for example here: https://jsfiddle.net/eput16mr/6/

This is a large image, the `width` / `height` attributes is the original image width / height divided by 100, but you still don't see layout shifts while the image loads.  When you remove those attributes, layout shifts start to occur, at least in my Chrome browser.  (Do a hard page refresh to force the browser to reload the image.)

Comment: I do not get any layout shifts that you stating. Those attributes do not take effect here at all when I test it (as I would expect too).

Comment: Wait, but if you remove the attributes, there is no way you don't get layout shifts?  The position of the text then depends only on the height data of the image, which hasn't loaded yet.  Maybe try hard refresh or throttling your connection in the network tab?

Comment: @tacoshy This is what it looks like to me without the attributes: https://i.imgur.com/dBEEfM1.mp4

Comment: if I throttle the internet then it comes back to the case of the ISO transportation layer.

Comment: I just ran a test on pagespeed.web.dev, where it shows the total CLS, and it confirms my observation, putting `width` and `height` attributes prevents layout shifts.  Also MDN says "Including height and width enables the aspect ratio of the image to be calculated by the browser prior to the image being loaded. This aspect ratio is used to reserve the space needed to display the image, reducing or even preventing a layout shift when the image is downloaded and painted to the screen."

Comment: But the interesting thing, and this is new to me, I usually use `* { all: unset; display: revert; }` as minimal CSS reset, it seems that this "reset" *also* causes layout shifts to happen.  What could be the property I'm resetting here which shouldn't be reseted?